# Only show first and last citation when referencing multiple references

Tags: biblatex

When I include multiple references for e.g. \cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}. I need it to output [1]-[3]. At the moment the result is [1, 2, 3]. IEEE is the formating style I require.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\cite{ref1, ref2, ref3}

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better if you can provide a minimal example we can use (copy-and-paste-and-compile) to replicate your current setup. The minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` styles only offer the form "[1-3]"

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1–3]]

But `biblatex-ieee` shows citations in the form "[1]-[3]"

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1]–[3]]

If you don't like the bibliography style that `style=ieee,` gives you, you can mix and match

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1]–[3]]

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: @Müller If this answer helped you, you may want to consider accepting it to show that your question is answered. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem by just adding the following this package:

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite} % 'sort' and 'compress' are enabled by default
```

Please do not forget to remove the old one, e.g., \usepackage{cite}